# Не работает изменение столбца в SQLite3

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, aiogram

Код должен после команды `/start` записывать в поля `user_id` и `username` следующие значения, полученные от `message.from_user.id` и `message.from_user_username`. Но в итоге у меня записывается только значение `user_id`

```
@dp.message_handler(commands='start')
async def start_command(message: types.Message):
    db.add_user(message.from_user.id)
    db.username( message.from_user.username, message.from_user.id)


class Database:
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def add_user(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'users' ('user_id') VALUES (?)", (user_id,))
            self.connection.commit()

    def username (self, username, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            self.cursor.execute("UPDATE 'users' SET 'username' = ? WHERE 'user_id' = ?", (username, user_id,))
            self.connection.commit()
```

Comment: Зачем вы 2мя итерациями это делаете? Сделайте в одной и таких проблем быть не должно. Одна из возможных причин, когда летит update, операция insert еще не закоммичена и update не находит записей в БД по переданному ID

Comment: я уже пытался так сделать. результат аналогичный

Comment: Здесь, кажется, чего-то не хватает в примере после последней запятой ``(username, user_id,)``

Comment: ну так если даже одной инструкцией не вставляется, может передаваемое значение username  пустое?

Comment: Значение username передается правильно. Можете предложить пример кода, как правильно вписать в одну строку и user_id и username

Comment: Можно попробовать ``self.cursor.execute("UPDATE 'users' SET 'username' = 'TestUSer' WHERE 'user_id' = ?", ( user_id))``

Comment: @ValNik Вышло ' self.cursor.execute("UPDATE 'users' SET 'username' = 'TestUSer' WHERE 'user_id' = ?", ( user_id))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: parameters are of unsupported type '
Столбец username является TEXT

Comment: @Frist `(user_id,)`

Comment: @ValNik все равно не работает. Чисто user_id заносится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sqlite3
import logging

from datetime import datetime

class Database:
    def __init__(self, db_file: str = "db.sqlite3") -> None:
        self.init_db(db_file)
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
    
    def init_db(self, db_file: str) -> None:
        """Инициализация базы данных.
        При инициализации базы данных создается таблица 'users' с полями 'id', 'user_id', 'username' и 'time'.
        Если таблица уже существует, ничего не делается."""

        with sqlite3.connect(db_file) as conn:
            conn.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
                            id          INTEGER     PRIMARY KEY,
                            user_id     BIGINT      NOT NULL,
                            username    VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
                            time        TEXT        NOT NULL)""")
            conn.commit()
    
    def check_user(self, user_id: int) -> bool:
        """Проверка существования пользователя в базе данных.
        Проверяет, существует ли пользователь с указанным user_id в базе данных."""

        with self.connection:
            self.cursor.execute("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id = ?", (user_id,))
            result = self.cursor.fetchone()
            return bool(result)
    
    def add_user(self, user_id: int, username: str) -> None:
        """Добавление нового пользователя в базу данных.        
        Добавляет нового пользователя с указанным user_id и username в базу данных."""

        current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        with self.connection:
            self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (user_id, username, time) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (user_id, username, current_time))
            self.connection.commit()
            logging.info(f"Добавлен пользователь с ID = {user_id} | username = {username}")
            
    def check_username(self, user_id: int, username: str) -> None:
        """Проверка изменения имени пользователя.
        При вводе команды /start проверяет, изменилось ли имя пользователя с user_id в базе данных.
        Если имя пользователя изменилось, вызывается функция update_username для обновления имени пользователя."""

        with self.connection:
            self.cursor.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE user_id = ?", (user_id,))
            result = self.cursor.fetchone()
            if result and result[0] != username:
                self.update_username(user_id, username)
                
    def update_username(self, user_id: int, username: str) -> None:
        """Обновление имени пользователя в базе данных.
        Обновляет имя пользователя с указанным user_id в базе данных."""

        current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        with self.connection:
            self.cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET username = ?, time = ? WHERE user_id = ?", (username, current_time, user_id))
            self.connection.commit()
            logging.info(f"Имя пользователя с ID = {user_id} был изменен на {username}")
```

---

Пример использоваения:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands="start")
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message) -> None:
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    username = message.from_user.username
    
    db = Database()

    if not db.check_user(user_id):
        db.add_user(user_id, username)
    else:
        db.check_username(user_id, username)
```